# Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 (ADLS Gen2) as a data source for Kedro pipeline

Tags: python, kedro, mlops

According to Kedro's [documentation](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.7/kedro.extras.datasets.html), Azure Blob Storage is one of the available data sources. Does this extend to ADLS Gen2 ?

Haven't tried Kedro yet, but before I invest some time on it, I wanted to make sure I could connect to ADLS Gen2.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this works with Kedro. You're actually pointing a really old version of the docs, nowadays all filesystem based datasets in Kedro use [fsspec](https://github.com/fsspec/filesystem_spec) under the hood which means they work with S3, HDFS, local and many more filesystems seamlessly.

The ADLS Gen2 is supported by `ffspec` via the underlying `adlfs` library which is [documented here](https://github.com/fsspec/adlfs).

From a Kedro point of view all you need to do is declare your catalog entry like so:

```yaml
 motorbikes:
     type: pandas.CSVDataSet
     filepath: abfs://your_bucket/data/02_intermediate/company/motorbikes.csv
     credentials: dev_az
```

We also have more examples [here](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/05_data/01_data_catalog.html), particularly example 15.